# What is the difference between "it seems" and "it looks like"?

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-usage, vocabulary, clauses, synonyms

Many times while I talked to others or wrote some text messages I got confusion about which phrase I should use to express the actual meaning of the words

> It seems . . .

and

> It looks like . . .

Please help me to clarify my doubts about how to use these words correctly?

Comment: "It seems" is equivalent to "it looks" (without the "like"), and an adjective is expected to follow those. "It seems that/like" and "It looks like" are also equivalent, but a verb is expected to follow. -> "Look at that fish, it looks/seems **dead**", "Look at that fish, it looks like/seems that/like **it's dead**." On another note, you can also use a noun after "looks like" and "seems like", but not after "seems that" -> "that fish looks/seems like **a shark**."

Comment: @MorganFR - Example where "it seems" and "it looks like" can replace one another, where you *can't* user "it looks" without the "like": *It seems I'm dying. It looks like I'm dying.* Example of a noun after "seems that": *Seems that poison can be hazardous to one's health.*

Comment: @nnnnnn I would personally use "It seems like/that I'm dying", but I suppose it can work too, because in a lot of cases, "that" is omited just like in "I think (that) I'm in love." However, "Seems (that) poison can..." is follow by a verbal clause, with "can" being the verb, you cannot use a noun group or a noun alone. Moreover, just as you said before, "that" can be omitted -> "Seems poison can..."

Comment: @MorganFR - Yeah, (it) seems (that) I was just being contrary.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence or two that you find confusing?

Comment: @MorganFR If you're going to answer the question, please **answer the question**. Comments are not a place for answers.

Comment: The two can be interchangeable: *It seems Carol got a haircut* ... *It looks like Carol got a haircut*...  also *It seems like Carol got a haircut*. But **not** *It looks Carol got a haircut*. The last one is ungrammatical in today's English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a subtle difference in usage between the two.

When we say "it looks like", we are talking about a quick visual inspection. If we want to investigate something casually, we say we will "take a look". The implication is that this is a brief, "at a glance" impression, and while we have some confidence we are not absolutely certain. "It looks like" is usually used to imply something we are *almost* certain about.  There is a saying:  "If it looks like a duck, and it walks like a duck, chances are... it's a duck."

When we say "it seems like", we are focusing on the impression given by the subject.  There is more doubt implied in this phrasing, because it suggests you may be deceived, where "it looks like" suggests you are likely correct.

Both phrases are often used humorously.  It's funny to use one of these phrases when the outcome is not in doubt.  ("Well, we're all gonna die here."  "Looks like.") ("That didn't work"  "Didn't seem to, no.") It's also funny to see someone use one of these phrases to show they are casual in a very serious situation:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bbzuu14bGgs

Comment: It is interesting that the relative amount of doubt in these phrases seems (or looks?) to be treated differently here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-seems-like-and-looks-like/answer/Hannah-Wiltbank